# Can't access chat, says I'm not logged in

Tags: support, chat

Was I banned or something? I don't see anything but that I need to login first.

Comment: You may not have global login working for stackexchange... i have that issue here at work and I have to use the workaround method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was simply a site wide problem. Seems to be fine for the past several hours.

Answer (score 0):

See http://chat.stackexchange.com/help

Which is linked from

http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq